# Illegal offset type, trying to save object

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, model, laravel-query-builder

code in controller.

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'user_id'=>'required',
        'book_id'=>'required',
        'rating'=>'required']);
```

have a composite primary key.

```
$rate = Rate::where('user_id', '=',$request->input('user_id'))
        ->where('book_id', '=', $request->input('book_id'))
        ->first();
```

try to save.

```
$rate->rating = $request->input('rating');
$rate->save();//error here
```

rate model is:

```
class Rate extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'rates';
    // primary key (['user_id', 'book_id'])
    public $primaryKey = ['user_id', 'book_id'];
    public $incrementing = false;   
    // timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

the problem I can't detect the error with **Illegal offset type**

Comment: You should provide the complete error-message including a stacktrace.
How does your `Rate` Model look like?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will make a difference, but try adding to your model: ```protected $fillable = ['rating'];```. Anyway, please provide the error message shown.

Comment: the error is Illegal offset type and can't detect what is wrong